# Is Array Sorted?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
public class Problem4 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         int n = sc.nextInt();
         int length = sc.nextInt();
         int[] arr = new int[length];
         for (int i : arr) {
             arr[0] = sc.nextInt();
         }
         boolean issorted = true;

         if (arr[length - 2] > arr[length - 1]) {
             issorted = false;
         } else {

                 issorted = true;
             }

             if (issorted) {
                 System.out.println("Yes");
             } else {
                 System.out.println("No");
             }
         }
     }
```

*I have problem with my homework.My task print only no.My condition is-Write a program that determines if an array of integers is sorted in increasing order.*

Examples:

Input: 1 2 4 8 12 34 200 2000
Output: Yes

Input: 7 8 9 10 11 12 11 13 9 
Outpur: No

Comment: Input                                         Output
1 2 4 8 12 34 200 2000 Yes
Input                                         Output
7 8 9 10 11 12 11 13 9 No

Answer (score 2):

You should use the for-loop iteration instead that checks *all* the elements in the array. The `if-else` statement is not useful for checking the whole array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) { // iterate from 0 to n-1 to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    int current = arr[i];                  // the x-th element
    int next = arr[i+1];                   // the (x+1)th element
    if (current >= next) {                 // if the previous > than the following one
        isSorted = false;                  // ... the array is no longer sorted
        break;                             // ... exit the iteration (makes no secne to continue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use a loop while comparing the elements.
2. You have added element only at index, `0` by using `arr[0] = sc.nextInt();`. It should be `arr[i] = sc.nextInt();`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the size of the array: ");
        int length = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[length];
        System.out.print("Enter " + length + " integers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        boolean isSorted = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i - 2] > arr[i - 1]) {
                isSorted = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isSorted) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the size of the array: 5
Enter 5 integers: 5 1 4 3 2
No
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the size of the array: 5
Enter 5 integers: 1 2 3 4 5
Yes
```

Comment: thank you.But what i can do in my program to be right.

Comment: @KristinaMihailova - I've updated the answer. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a one liner in form of a function:

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length - 1).allMatch(i -> array[i] <= array[i + 1]);
}
```